# Installing Sitecore Experience Platform 9.3 giving error "test-path $_"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

I'm trying to configure sitecore on my local system
Installing from Sitecore Install Assistant.
1st step Prerequisites are Installed
2nd step Solr Installation is done and working on local host.
3rd Sitecore Settings also done.
4th SQL Server settings also done onward till Validation everything works fine.
On last step assistent giving me Error.
Error: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Source'. The " Test-Path $_ " validation script for the argument with value "C:\Solr\Solr-8.1.1\server\solr\configsets_default*" did not return a result of True. Determine why the validation script failed, and then try the command again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this happened due to the Solr version. Newer versions use "default" as part of the folder name on that path (C:\Solr\Solr-8.1.1\server\solr\configsets_default) while older versions use "basic_configs".

To solve this, I had to edit the JSON files with the solr parameters so the installation wizard could find the right paths.

I replaced "_default" to "basic_configs" in the field located at Parameters > BaseConfig > DefaultValue.
I did this for all the .json files that have SOLR in its name (Eg: "-solr.json").